# get TextView from another class

Tags: java, android

I want to display this textview "txtCalculate" which comes from the class CustomerMapActivity which is displayed in the activity_map_customer layout in another layout which is activity_bon_de_commande, of the class BonDeCommande.
the problem is I don't know how to do it
I'm new to java programming
thank you

```
    public void readValues(){

    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Query lastQuery = ref.child("ride_info").orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
    lastQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){


                double value0_float = ds.child("pickup").child("lat").getValue(Double.class);
                double value1_float = ds.child("pickup").child("lng").getValue(Double.class);
                double value2_float = ds.child("destination").child("lat").getValue(Double.class);
                double value3_float = ds.child("destination").child("lng").getValue(Double.class);

                String pickupLat = String.valueOf(value0_float);
                String pickupLng = String.valueOf(value1_float);
                String destiLat = String.valueOf(value2_float);
                String destiLng = String.valueOf(value3_float);

                String requestUrl=null;
                try {
                    requestUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?"+
                            "mode=driving&"
                            +"transit_routing_preference=less_driving&"
                            +"origin="+pickupLat+","+pickupLng+"&"
                            +"destination="+destiLat+","+destiLng+"&"
                            +"key="+getResources().getString(R.string.google_maps_key);
                    Log.e("LINK",requestUrl);
                    mService.getPath(requestUrl).enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().toString());
                                JSONArray routes = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes");

                                JSONObject object = routes.getJSONObject(0);
                                JSONArray legs = object.getJSONArray("legs");

                                JSONObject legsObject = legs.getJSONObject(0);

                                //Get distance
                                JSONObject distance = legsObject.getJSONObject("distance");
                                String distance_text = distance.getString("text");
                                //use regex to extract double from string
                                //This regex will remove all text not digit
                                Double distance_value= Double.parseDouble(distance_text.replaceAll("[^0-9\\\\.]+",""));

                                //Get Time
                                JSONObject time = legsObject.getJSONObject("duration");
                                String time_text = time.getString("text");
                                Integer time_value = Integer.parseInt(time_text.replaceAll("\\D+",""));

                                String final_calculate = String.format("%.2f €",
                                        TypeObject.getPrice(distance_value,time_value));

             HERE ----->        txtCalculate.setText(final_calculate);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                            mCurrentRide.cancelRide();
                            endRide();

                        }
                    });
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            mCurrentRide.cancelRide();
            endRide();
        }
    });
}
```

screenshot of my screen

[image]

Comment: See clean architecture. Solves your problem and hundreds of other you don't know you have yet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Create an Interface with an update method, declare in your Activity and after, pass as parameter to your handler object that gets the data.

Don't forget If you're getting the data in a different Thread, you need to update your views always in an UI Thread or in the Main Thread.

Here Follow some example code:

Your Activity or Fragment

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements UpdateViewCallback { // implement the interface here

    private TextView textView = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

        // Pass the interface in your Object that makes the async work
        final AsyncWork asyncWork = new AsyncWork(this);

        // Running
        Thread thread = new Thread(asyncWork);
        thread.start();
    }

    /**
     * UpdateViewCallback
     * @param result
     */
    @Override
    public void updateView(final String result) {
        // Always update View on MainThread or an UI Thread, or else issues will start to happening
        this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Check if View is null since you're updating in a thread async
                if (textView != null) {
                    textView.setText(result);
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Your Interface:

```
public interface UpdateViewCallback {
    void updateView(String result);
}
```

Your Object to handle the Async Work:

```
public class AsyncWork implements Runnable {

    private  UpdateViewCallback updateViewCallback;

    public AsyncWork(UpdateViewCallback updateViewCallback) {
        this.updateViewCallback = updateViewCallback;
    }

    /**
     * Async Work here
     */
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do some Work and after update using the interface you passed in the constructor
        updateViewCallback.updateView("This is a test");
    }
}
```

Comment: can you give me an exemple ? please

Comment: Give some time, I send you an example

Comment: Done, check if it can help you, read the comments and ask me if you have doubts.